# Python: Passing value of a string variable as argument in Popen

Tags: python

What is the proper way to pass values of string variables to Popen function in Python? I tried the below piece of code

```
var1 = 'hello'
var2 = 'universe'
p=Popen('/usr/bin/python /apps/sample.py ' + '"' + str(eval('var1')) + ' ' + '"' + str(eval('var2')), shell=True)
```

and in sample.py, below is the code

```
print sys.argv[1]
print '\n'
print sys.argv[2]
```

but it prints the below output

```
hello universe
none
```

so its considering both var1 and var2 as one argument. Is this the right approach of passing values of string variables as arguments?

Comment: `str(eval('var1'))`is the same as `'var1'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
p = Popen('/usr/bin/python /apps/sample.py {} {}'.format(var1, var2), shell=True)
```

Learn about [string formatting](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-examples) .

Second, passing arguments to scripts has its quirks: http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen

This works for me:

test.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys

print sys.argv[1]
print '\n'
print sys.argv[2]
```

Then:

```
chmod +x test.py
```

Then:

```
Python 2.7.4 (default, Jul  5 2013, 08:21:57) 
>>> from subprocess import Popen
>>> p = Popen('./test.py {} {}'.format('hello', 'universe'), shell=True)
>>> hello


universe
```

Comment: and is there a way to return control from the called python script to the calling python script?

Comment: The control is returned to the called script when it terminates.

Answer (score 0):

```
var1 = 'hello'
var2 = 'universe'
p=Popen("/usr/bin/python /apps/sample.py %s %s"%(str(eval('var1')), str(eval('var2'))), shell=True)
```

Passing format specifier is nice way to do it.